# cannot load multiple rows into a TableLayout from the same xml source

Tags: java, android, android-tablayout

I have `TableLayout`   and I want to load rows dynamically from the same file i.e `automationrow.xml` which is actually a predefined table row.Here is my Row that I want to duplicate.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/R2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/r2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:alpha="1"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp">

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/heading_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="@color/title"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_heading"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:text="Room 2"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/room1"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:alpha="1"
                android:background="#292828"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="20dp">

                <Switch
                    android:id="@+id/mySwitchr2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="bulb1    "
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <Switch
                    android:id="@+id/mySwitch2r2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/mySwitchr1"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="bulb2"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <Switch
                    android:id="@+id/mySwitch3r2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/mySwitchr1"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="bulb3"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <Switch
                    android:id="@+id/mySwitch4r2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/mySwitchr1"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="Fan"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <SeekBar
                    android:id="@+id/seekBar2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="25dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</TableRow>
```

And I am doing this inside a fragment and running the following code but it breaks after adding just one row with the following error

**java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.controls, container, false);        
    TableLayout Tab =(TableLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.table);
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.automationrow, container,false);
    TableRow newr = (TableRow) view.findViewById(R.id.R1);
    for (int i=1;i<=2;i++){
        Tab.addView(newr);
        Log.d("check runs",String.valueOf(i)); //printed only once
        //Tab is the TableLayout
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 for (int i=1;i<=2;i++){

     View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.automationrow, container,false);
     TableRow newr = (TableRow) view.findViewById(R.id.R1);
     Tab.addView(newr);
     Log.d("check runs",String.valueOf(i)); //printed only once
     //Tab is the TableLayout
}
```